# Multi stores with different CSS

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, css, html

How is the workaround with multi-store, if I want to add different style with the CSS.

In one of the stores, i want to hide the old price (Just by settings the font-size to 0px). The stores is on following URL xxxxxxx.dk/store1 and xxxxxxx.dk/store2

How can i make the CSS only take affect on store1, and keep the default for store2

```
.page .category-products .products-container ul li.item .price-box .old-price .price {
    font-size: 0px;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #d3d3d3;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: none;
}
```

EDIT:

I have tried with the following settings:

[image]

But it look like this:
[image]

My standard page works fine, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For This, you can assume one store as Main (store1) that contain all the templates and Skin.

For sub Stores (store2, Store3) You can create another Skin folder for each sub store with your customization. and mention the Particular Store Skin in `System -> Configuration -> Design`.

**Updated:**

You can check configuration from below image:

[image]

Comment: So the Current Package Name should be the same in both stores? And then the theme should be different, or do i misunderstand you @PankajPareek? :-)

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: I have edited the question, and added screenshot of my setup @PankajPareek

Comment: Only mention skin folder name and leave others unchecked. I am assuming you have copied complete skin folder and then added your changes